# UserInformation.getFirstNameAsync Promise Never Gets Fulfilled

Tags: javascript, windows-8

Anyone have any idea why I would never even hit a debugger here? When I first ran I hit the error method and it said I needed Enterprise Authentication enabled, but now I don't hit either debugger. I do get a get a promise back from the getFirstNameAsync, but it just never fulfills I guess.

```
Windows.System.UserProfile.UserInformation.getFirstNameAsync().done(
    function (name) {
        debugger; //document.getElementById("myDiv").innerText = name;
    },
    function (error) {
        debugger; //document.getElementById("myDiv").innerText = error.message;
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple system restart fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a try {} catch() {} block around any code that can cause an exception.

Async methods will just stop executing on the thread they are created on if an exception occurs.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure why I didn't think of that. So I wrapped it, and then suddenly I started hitting my success debugger. I removed the try catch and it works. I think it was another issue... perhaps a system restart fixed it or something.